# Correct Sizing of Markers In Scatter Plot to a Radius R in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a plot with limits -1 to 1.
I know the scatter plot doesn't plot with size as a radius, it plots with size as a point.

I need my plot to be scaled correctly with the size of each point, which I have as a radius.
Is this possible with modifications to the below code?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set_title("Post Synaptic Neurons")
sizes = [x.size * 100 for x in post_synaptic_neurons]
offsets = [(x.origin[0],x.origin[1]) for x in post_synaptic_neurons]
print(sizes)
ax.scatter([x.origin[0] for x in post_synaptic_neurons], [x.origin[1] for x in post_synaptic_neurons], 
  cmap=plt.cm.hsv, s=sizes, alpha=0.5)
ax.set_xlim([-1,1]) 
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.tight_layout
```

If no, can someone explain to me why matplotlib doesn't have a function for plotting a circle with a particular radius on the scale of the plot?
I didn't expect this to be an issue, but there must be a good reason behind my difficulties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is not a high-level way to do this, but you can make it work with an `EllipseCollection`. Since your data isn't available, I made some up and wrote this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import EllipseCollection

x, y = 1500 * np.random.rand(2, 100)
size = 50 + 10 * np.random.randn(100)
color = np.random.rand(100)
cmap = plt.cm.hsv

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16, 6),
                       sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax[0].scatter(x, y, s=size, c=color, cmap=cmap)

offsets = list(zip(x, y))
ax[1].add_collection(EllipseCollection(widths=size, heights=size, angles=0, units='xy',
                                       facecolors=plt.cm.hsv(color),
                                       offsets=offsets, transOffset=ax[1].transData))
ax[1].axis('equal') # set aspect ratio to equal
ax[1].axis([-400, 1800, -200, 1600])
```

The result is what you hope for; simple scatter plot on the left, scaled plot on the right:
[image]

If you scale the plots, say by changing the axis limits to `ax[1].axis([200, 1000, 300, 900])`, then the circles on the right plot scale as desired:

[image]

You can find more examples of using collections in the [matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/collections_demo.html).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a way to plot scatters with a specific radius on the scale of the plot. The way is to carefully define the figure size and specify the radius in the number of points, since the documentation for `plt.scatter` says the argument `s` is "The marker size in points**2".

Here's an example that plots a circle with radius 0.1 at the position [0.5, 0.5]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=[5, 5])
ax = plt.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1))
points_whole_ax = 5 * 0.8 * 72    # 1 point = dpi / 72 pixels
radius = 0.1
points_radius = 2 * radius / 1.0 * points_whole_ax
ax.scatter(0.5, 0.5, s=points_radius**2, color='r')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The key here is that the standard size of points in matplotlib is 72 points per inch (ppi), no matter the dpi. The factor of 2 in the formula of `points_radius` comes from the fact that the area is the area of a box just outside of the shere, i.e. `area = (2 * radius)**2`. The output figure is shown below.

[image: A circle with a radius of 0.1 in code scale, plot with plt.scatter]

Comment: Why is 
plt.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1))
important? I mean why can't I work without specifying the width and height of Axes.

Answer (score 0):

**Limitation of existing solutions in this question:**

I have tried Jordan He's and jakevdp's solution (two answers below this question), and I find Jordan He's solution only working with figure sizes that are carefully (manually) designed. Jakevdp's code is Python-2, which not fit Python-3.

The biggest problem of Jordan He's solution is that the size of 'scatter' is limited to circle. That is to say, when the range of x-axis and y-axis are not equal, although the 'scatter' looks like a circle, it's actually a ellipse numerically.

**My solution:**

In short, I refer to [matplotlib demo about ellipse](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/pylab_examples/ellipse_demo.html).

I use `matplotlib.patches.Ellipse` to plot a ellipse(numerically), and make it precisely the size (not inch, but values like those in axis) I set manually.

That is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

x = 5
y = 5
e = Ellipse(xy=(x,y), width=6, height=10, angle=0) # set the width and heiget with number you want, this would be precisely numerical to the axis

fig = plt.figure(0)
# ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, aspect='equal') # add a plot, making the x-axis and y-axis equally looked

ax.add_artist(e)
e.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)
e.set_facecolor('#C0C0C0') # color here could be RGB like (0,0,0)

ax.set_xlim(0, 10) # set the range of x-axis
ax.set_ylim(0, 10) # set the range of y-axis

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```